# Java Spark: Non-blocking routes / callbacks with CompletableFutures

Tags: java, multithreading, callback, future, spark-java

I have to make calls to long running methods in a Spark API implementation. These methods return CompletableFutures, so I'd like to free up the current Thread by triggering Spark to answer the client request in a callback.
As far as I can tell this is not possible with Spark, but I'd like to make sure I am not overlooking anything. 
To illustrate the question, see the small code sample below.

```
import spark.Spark;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class HelloSpark {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Spark.get("/what_i_have_to_do", (req, res) -> {
            CompletableFuture<String> f = callToSlowWorker();
            return f.get();
        });

        Spark.get("/what_i_would_like_to_do", (req, res) -> {
            CompletableFuture<String> f = callToSlowWorker();
            f.whenComplete((answer, throwable) -> {
                if(throwable != null){
                    // send error to requesting client
                    res.status(500);
                    res.body(throwable.getMessage());
                } else {
                    // send answer to requesting client
                    res.body(answer);
                }
                // trigger spark to return the response to the client
                // ...?!?
            });
            return null; // obviously not what I want, just to make this sample code compile
        });
    }

    static CompletableFuture<String> callToSlowWorker(){
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
            return "Hello World";
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SparkJava is currently blocking only, thus what you've described is not possible. There is an open [enhancement request](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/208) to add support for a non blocking API.